# function to count changes in a network (changes in node attributes)

Tags: r, networking

I would like to count the number of color changes in a network using a function.

A change would be `"red"` to `"green"` (from `a` to `b` in the example)

Overlaps (e.g., `"green"` to `"green"` and `"orange"`, from `c` to `c1` in the example) should not count as a change.

Example data:

```
library(tidyverse)


network <- tibble(
  from=c("a","b","c","c"),
  to= c("b","c","c1","c2"))


colors <- list(
  a=list("red"),
  b=list("red"),
  c=list("green"),
  c1=list("green","orange"),
  c2=list("blue","black")
)
```

The correct output of the function would be 2 (from `b` to `c` and `c` to `c2`) in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be vectorized:

```r
# change inner lists in 'colors' to vectors
colors <- lapply(colors, unlist)

count_color_changes <- function(network, colors) {
  
  # list of lists of 'from' and to 'colors'
  col.ft <- lapply(network, \(x) colors[x])
  # common colors
  col.com <- mapply(intersect, col.ft$from, col.ft$to)
  # number of transitions where no common color was found
  sum(sapply(col.com, length) == 0)
}

count_color_changes(network, colors)
# 2
```

Comment: thank you for the hint. I corrected the desired output. what is the advantage of the vectorization?  I have a grouped df with many networks and I would like to map a function to every group.

Comment: I meant vectorization as opposed to the other answer which uses a `for` loop, which will be less efficient.